# camera app with collection view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am very new to XCode and Swift. Hope you guys can give me a hand here. I am having a problem that when I click the camera button, and snap a photo and click "Use Photo", the camera will be dismissed and back to the main page again.

What I actually want : 
When I click "Use Photo" the main page should show the image taken just now in thumbnail size in collection view. 
[Camera Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRr1b.jpg)
[The expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibYN4.jpg)

Here is my code :

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import Photos
import PhotosUI
import MessageUI

let albumName = "CP"

class SpeakerViewController: UIViewController, 
CLLocationManagerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, 
UINavigationControllerDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, 
UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, 
MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {
@IBOutlet var lblLocation: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var tvNews: UITextView!
@IBOutlet var tapView: UIView!
@IBOutlet var btnAlbum: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var btnCamera: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var btnSend: UIButton!

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()

var latitude = [String]()
var longitude = [String]()
var tap : UITapGestureRecognizer! = UITapGestureRecognizer()
var assetCollection: PHAssetCollection! = PHAssetCollection()

var photoAsset : PHFetchResult<PHAsset>!

var albumFound : Bool = false
var sendLocation : String = ""
var sendContent : String = ""
var imageArray = [UIImage]()
var isCamera : Bool = false

@IBAction func btnBack(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
        PHAssetChangeRequest.deleteAssets(self.photoAsset)
        }, completionHandler: {(success, error) in
            NSLog("Delete image => %@", (success ? "Success" : "Error"))
            self.navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    })
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    LocalStore.setActiveView("speaker")
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 237/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1.0)

    if(locationManager.responds(to: #selector(CLLocationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization))) {
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    }
    locationManager.delegate = self

    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(SpeakerViewController.DismissKeyboard))
    let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
    fetchOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title = %@", albumName)
    let collection:PHFetchResult = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .album, subtype: .any, options: fetchOptions)

    if let first_Obj:AnyObject = collection.firstObject{
        //found the album
        self.albumFound = true
        self.assetCollection = first_Obj as! PHAssetCollection
    } else {
        var albumPlaceholder:PHObjectPlaceholder!
        NSLog("\nFolder \"%@\" does not exist\nCreating now...", albumName)
        PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
            let request = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetCollection(withTitle: albumName)
            albumPlaceholder = request.placeholderForCreatedAssetCollection
            },

            completionHandler: {success, error in
                if(success){
                    print("Successfully created folder")
                    self.albumFound = true
                    let collection = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(withLocalIdentifiers: [albumPlaceholder.localIdentifier], options: nil)
                    self.assetCollection = collection.firstObject as PHAssetCollection!
                } else {
                    print("Error creating folder")
                    self.albumFound = false
                }
        })
    }

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
        selector: #selector(SpeakerViewController.keyboardShow(_:)),
        name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidShow,
        object: nil)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
        selector: #selector(SpeakerViewController.keyboardHide(_:)),
        name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidHide,
        object: nil)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
        selector: #selector(SpeakerViewController.applicationBecameActive(_:)),
        name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive,
        object: nil)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
        selector: #selector(SpeakerViewController.applicationBecameInactive(_:)),
        name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillResignActive,
        object: nil)
}

/* Start listening for iCloud user change notifications */
func applicationBecameActive(_ notification: Notification){
    print("did become active notification")
    if LocalStore.getPostIdMenu() != "0" {
        self.navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        LocalStore.setPostIdMenu("0")
    }
}

func applicationBecameInactive(_ notification: Notification){
    print("did become inactive notification")
    LocalStore.setPostIdMenu("0")
}

func keyboardShow(_ notification: Notification) {
    print("Keyboard Show")
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

func keyboardHide(_ notification: Notification){
    print("Keyboard Hide")
    self.view.removeGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    //fetch the photo from the collection
    self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = false
    self.photoAsset = PHAsset.fetchAssets(in: self.assetCollection, options: nil)
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "出现错误", message: "无法检索您的位置", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "好的", style: .default){ _ in})
    self.present(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)
}



func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    latitude.removeAll()
    longitude.removeAll()

    let currentLocation = locations.last!

    print("didUpdateToLocation: \(currentLocation)")

    latitude.append(String(format: "%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude))
    longitude.append(String(format: "%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude))

    print("Latitude \(latitude.count), Longtitude \(longitude.count)")

    geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(currentLocation, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in
        if(error == nil && placemarks!.count > 0 ) {
            let placeMark = placemarks![0] as CLPlacemark

            if (placeMark.addressDictionary?["Thoroughfare"] as? String) != nil {

                self.lblLocation.text = "\(placeMark.thoroughfare!), \(placeMark.postalCode!), \(placeMark.administrativeArea!)"
                print("Location \(placeMark.locality!)\(placeMark.country!)")
                self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
                self.sendLocation = self.lblLocation.text!
            } else {
                print("thoroughfare not found, reupdate coordinate")
                self.locationManager.delegate = self
                self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
                self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            }
        } else {
            NSLog("%@", error.debugDescription)
        }
    })
}

func DismissKeyboard() {
    view.endEditing(true)
}

@IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!
@IBAction func btnAlbum(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    isCamera = false

    if(UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.savedPhotosAlbum)) {
        let imagePicker : UIImagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
        imagePicker.mediaTypes = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypes(for: .photoLibrary)!
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

@IBAction func btnCamera(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    isCamera = true
    if(UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera)) {
        let imagePicker : UIImagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "出现错误", message: "您的手机没有相机", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "好的", style: .default, handler: {(alertAction) in
            alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }))

        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

@IBAction func btnSend(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    var count : Int = 0
    if(self.photoAsset != nil) {
        count = self.photoAsset.count
    }

    if (tvNews.text != "" && count > 0) {
        sendContent = tvNews.text

        if (MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail()) {
            let emailTitle = "App"
            let messageBody = "位置: \(sendLocation) \n\n \(sendContent) \n\n "
            let toReceipients = ["test@com"]
            let mc : MFMailComposeViewController = MFMailComposeViewController()
            mc.mailComposeDelegate = self
            mc.setSubject(emailTitle)
            mc.setMessageBody(messageBody, isHTML: false)
            mc.setToRecipients(toReceipients)
}
            for image in self.imageArray {
                let photoData : Data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)!
                mc.addAttachmentData(photoData, mimeType: "image/png", fileName: "CP.png")
            }

            self.present(mc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            print("No email account found")
        }
    } else {
        let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "出现错误", message: "没有内容或照片", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "好的", style: .default, handler: {(alertAction) in
            alertView.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }))
        self.present(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    var count : Int = 0
    if(self.photoAsset != nil) {
        count = self.photoAsset.count
    }

    return count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell: PhotoCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "PhotoCell", for: indexPath) as! PhotoCollectionViewCell
    let asset : PHAsset = self.photoAsset[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).item] as PHAsset

    PHImageManager.default().requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: PHImageManagerMaximumSize, contentMode: .aspectFill, options: nil, resultHandler: {(result, info) in
        if let image = result {
            cell.setThumbnailImage(image)
            self.imageArray.append(image)
        }
    })

    return cell
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if(segue.identifier == "viewLargePhoto") {
        if let controller:ViewPhotoViewController = segue.destination as? ViewPhotoViewController {
            if let cell = sender as? UICollectionViewCell {
                if let indexPath: IndexPath = self.collectionView.indexPath(for: cell) {
                    controller.index = (indexPath as NSIndexPath).item
                    controller.photoAsset = self.photoAsset
                    controller.assetCollection = self.assetCollection
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 4
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 1
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if(isCamera) {
        let image = info["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] as! UIImage
        PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
            let createAssetRequest = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAsset(from: image)
            let assetPlaceholder = createAssetRequest.placeholderForCreatedAsset
            if let albumChangeRequest = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest(for: self.assetCollection,              
                assets: self.photoAsset as PHFetchResult<PHAsset>) {

                let enumeration: NSArray = [assetPlaceholder!]
                albumChangeRequest.addAssets(enumeration)
            }
            //CORRECTION Error : App crashes
            }, completionHandler: {(success, error) in
                NSLog("Adding Image to Library => %@",(success ? "Success" : "Error!"))
                //Relocated1

        })
        //CORRECTION Relocated1

        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    } else {
        let image = info["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] as! UIImage
        PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
            let createAssetRequest = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAsset(from: image)
            let assetPlaceholder = createAssetRequest.placeholderForCreatedAsset
            if let albumChangeRequest = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest(for: self.assetCollection,

                assets: self.photoAsset as PHFetchResult<PHAsset>) {

                let enumeration: NSArray = [assetPlaceholder!]
                albumChangeRequest.addAssets(enumeration)
            }
            }, completionHandler: {(success, error) in
                NSLog("Adding Image to Library => %@",(success ? "Success" : "Error!"))
                picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                //self.navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        })
    }
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
    switch result {
    case .cancelled:
        let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "取消电邮", message: "您已经取消电邮", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "好的", style: .default, handler: {(alertAction) in
            alertView.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }))
        self.present(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)
    case .saved:
        let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "保存电邮", message: "您已经保存电邮", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "好的", style: .default, handler: {(alertAction) in
            alertView.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }))
        self.present(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)
    case .sent:
        let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "发送电邮", message: "您已经发送您的电邮", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "好的", style: .default, handler: {(alertAction) in
            alertView.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }))
        self.present(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)
    case .failed:
        let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "发送失败", message: "请检查您的电邮设定", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "好的", style: .default, handler: {(alertAction) in
            alertView.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }))
        self.present(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)
    //CORRECTION default:
      //  break
    default :
        break
    }

    self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is it required to use photos Framework even when you are clicking a picture. just use normal picker to get the image either from gallery or from camera save it in Document Directory and then use Photos Framework to get image from directory as PhAsset so can be deleted or modified later.  just directly pass image from camera to imageView on main screen and then save image there if required

Comment: Thank you for you help. I actually kind of restructured my codes. Cause this code triggered another issue.